# iOS Facebook sign in failed

Tags: ios, facebook-login

It shows

> This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to
>   it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for
>   permissions.

But I have made GuGu public under Facebook dev website's App Review tag(Turned on the switch), and it show

> Your app is currently live and available to the public.

I may needn't public this app for now, because I just wanna test Facebook sign in with dev account or some test accounts.

Comment: when this warning you got ?

Comment: If you need to test Facebook in `development mode`, then App creation email & login email should be same

Comment: This is my fault, I filled out the previous Facebook AppID... And thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable  this option in developer.facebook.com if you want to live your app as below  :
[image]

Comment: But yes I have turned on.

Comment: do you want test app  or upload to appstore ?

Comment: My fault, I filled out the previous Facebook AppID... And thank you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com -> YOUR_APP -> App Review -> Make app public to **YES**

Comment: But I had do this

Comment: Are you able to login successfully to the app using the fb account in which you have set up the app ?

Comment: My fault, I filled out the previous Facebook AppID... And thank you :)